# Grails locale-independent decimal databinding

Tags: grails, data-binding

**What is the problem:**

In my application, numbers on the front-end are always presented with a `,` as a decimal separator. The problem with wrong binding occurs when an user changes his locale and edits the entity with `?lang=en_EN` parameter. What happens is that with `en_EN` locale, the decimal separator is `.` which makes value on the input `11,00`, `1100` in the database, instead of `11.00` - critical problem when it comes to money.

**Software used:**

```
Grails 2.3.8
Groovy 2.2.1
```

**What I want to do:**

In my case the default "locale aware" approach in converters is very problematic, and I want them to be binded always the same way, which should be locale-independent.

**What I have already tried:**

I found that what makes the job by default is `LocaleAwareNumberConverter` and more specifically `LocaleAwareBigDecimalConverter`, so I wrote a simple implementation which simply uses one locale (in this case `GERMAN`, as it uses `,` as a decimal separator)

```
@CompileStatic
class MyBigDecimalConverter extends LocaleAwareNumberConverter {

    @Override
    protected NumberFormat getNumberFormatter() {
        NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN)
    }
}
```

included it in the `resources.groovy`:

```
myBigDecimalConverter com.company.converters.MyBigDecimalConverter
```

But it just doesn't work. Values are still converted with `LocaleAwareBigDecimalConverter`.

**EDIT**:

I've changed my converter to directly implement `ValueConverter`:

```
@CompileStatic
class MyBigDecimalConverter implements ValueConverter {

    @Override
    boolean canConvert(Object value) {
        value instanceof String
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object value) {
        def numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN)
        numberFormatter.parse((String)value).asType(getTargetType())
    }

    @Override
    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        BigDecimal
    }
}
```

And this converter also doesn't get called. I made no changes to the `resources.groovy`

Comment: I don't have time to check today (not working), but this similar question has an answer worth investigating (in case you haven't seen it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274274/binding-real-number-values-to-grails-domain-attributes-values-sent-by-dojo-widg?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it working now. It is based on my code, but should work for you as well.

To register your own `ValueConverter` for `BigDecimal`, you should add `defaultGrailsBigDecimalConverter(YourBigDecimalValueConverter)` to *resources.groovy*. I derived that conclusion from *DataBindingGrailsPlugin.groovy* for Grails 2.3.11.

If you have `grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = true` in *Config.groovy*, you need to remove that to enable the new data binding for Grails 2.3.

My `ValueConverter` is similar to your your second sample that implements it directly, so use that one first to minimize other problems that might occur.

That's all there is to it. I have implemented a `ValueConverter` that accepts both dot and comma as separator and then presents it according to the user's locale. It is working, the tricky part was figuring out the correct name for *resources.groovy* and at the same time have the Spring binder disabled.

Comment: Hi! Have you had time to test this solution and did you get it to work for you as well?

Comment: Yes, and it worked! So the only problem left for me was wiring it with a right name. And that was `defaultGrailsBigDecimalConverter`. Thank you *very*, very much! And congratulations, bounty hunter, you won the prize! :-)

Comment: Great to hear! It's funny, but the bounty actually made a difference. It made me prioritize my tasks differently and "just go for this now for the bonus" :-) Good to know when I get stuck!