# Grails 2.5.3 not binding float fields correctly

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class with a float field:

```
class DvQuantity {

   float magnitude
   String units
}
```

When I have this:

```
new DvQuantity( magnitude: '11.0', units: 'm' ).save()
```

In the database I see: **magnitude = 110.0 instead of 11.0**

Is this a Grails bug? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I've seen quite a few bugs in Grails binding, so quite might be a bug.
But check you locale first. I believe Grails use user locale to parse numbers, in which case the '.' might just mean nothing in your locale, causing the behavior.
As an option, you can parse it yourself this way:
new DvQuantity( magnitude: new BigDecimal('11.0'), units: 'm' ).save()

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. As stated in the comment, parsing of numbers depends on your locale. See example below:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat
String a = '11,0'
assert NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).parse(a).floatValue() == 110
assert NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse(a).floatValue() == 11.0
```

There are many different ways to change your default number format - for example `PropertyEditorRegistrar` or `ValueConverter`. You can also enforce format on the view using validators.

Here [Grails databinding with decimal delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877602/grails-databinding-with-decimal-delimiter) is answer with example code how to do that for Grails <2.3 and >=2.4

Comment: the strange thing is I'm running 2 apps in my machine, create data on app1 as 11.0, send that to app2, which stores it correctly as 11.0, retrieve data from app2 and appears as 11.0 on app1, but when I try to save that to app1 database, it appears as 110.0

Comment: How do you send data from one app to another? if you are sending numbers instead of strings, then number format is not needed and it will be correctly saved - for example when you use JSON. Problem is only when you have to parse string to number.